# How Could One Read 4649?

Tags: names, numbers, puns

In the Japanese version of Smash 4 for the Wii U, if you let the game come up with a name for you, one of the names it pops out is 4649. I'm assuming this is some joke based on the readings of the numbers being read as a name, but I can't quite decipher what it's supposed to be. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's [４]{よ}[６]{ろ}[４]{し}[９]{く}......

Comment: 速っ！かなんなあ、省エネアンサーには・・

Comment: Does よろしく as a name mean something?

Comment: No, it's just the regular word. It was just my mistaken assumption that it would be a name.

Comment: Well, 5963 to you

Comment: @wil [３９]{さんきゅう}...

Comment: For anyone interested, the term for these kinds of phrase is [語呂合わせ (goroawase)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_wordplay#Numeric_substitution).